# iTextSharp convert a System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, charts

I have a report like page which displays a gridview and a chart created from .Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting which I want to convert to pdf.  Currently I am using iTextSharp which in my opinion is really great.  I managed to create the table in the pdf but cannot find a way how to display the chart as well. Any ideas pls..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`chart.Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.paint.aspx) to render the chart to a `Bitmap` object.
You can then add the image to the PDF as described [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images).